# how to take different value from numberpicker in listview for different items

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-studio

I want to take quantity from user through number picker. I am getting value but the value entered by one number picker duplicates in all other number pickers also. Can You please help me with the code

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  ListView mListView;
  Button btnShowCheckedItems;
  ArrayList<Menu> mMenus;
  MultiSelectionAdapter<Menu> mAdapter;
  HashMap<Integer,Integer> quantityList;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bindComponents();
    init();
    addListeners();
  }
  private void bindComponents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    btnShowCheckedItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowCheckedItems);
  }
  private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMenus = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    mMenus.add(new Menu("Pendrive"));
    mMenus.add(new Menu("Laptop"));
    mMenus.add(new Menu("Mouse"));

    quantityList=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    quantityList=null;

    mAdapter = new MultiSelectionAdapter<Menu>(this, mMenus);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
  private void addListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btnShowCheckedItems.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mAdapter != null) {
      ArrayList<Menu> mArrayMenus = mAdapter.getCheckedItems();
      Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Selected Items: " + mArrayMenus.toString());
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Items: " + mArrayMenus.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item-qty"+quantityList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

MultiSelectionAdapter.java

```
package com.example.anjali.mylistviewdemo;

/**
 * Created by jaisnain on 17/3/16.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MultiSelectionAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter{
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<T> mList;
    NumberPicker np;
    TextView tv1;
    String newV;
    SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
    public MultiSelectionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mList = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.mList = list;


    }
    public ArrayList<T> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<T> mTempArry = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(int i=0;i<mList.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(mList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return mTempArry;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
    @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        np.setMinValue(0);
        np.setMaxValue(10);
        np.setValue(0);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

        TextView tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        tv1.setTag(position);

        np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //newV = newVal + " ";
                if (newVal > 0) {
                    //mSparseBooleanArray.put(position, true);
                    System.out.println("Position:"+position+"NewVal:"+newVal);
                    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
                    m.quantityList.put(position, newVal);
                    tv1.setText(newVal);

                }
                //System.out.println("New Value:" + newV);
            }
        });

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(mList.get(position).toString());




        CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkEnable);
        mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

        return convertView;
    }
    OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };
}
```

Menu.java

```
package com.example.anjali.mylistviewdemo;

/**
 * Created by jaisnain on 17/3/16.
 */

public class Menu {
    String name;

public Menu(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = name;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnShowCheckedItems"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowCheckedItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Show"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkEnable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chkEnable"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkEnable"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkEnable" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="qty"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvTitle" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's interesting, so all rows show the same values?

Comment: I think the problem is with: `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
                    m.quantityList.put(position, newVal);` Creating a new activity each time instead getting the instance something like: `((MainActivity) getActivity()).getQuantityList.put(position, newVal);`

Comment: so how should I solve it?

Comment: I would start by commenting out the new mainactivity piece to see if that changes the output. I don't see anything obvious that stands out

Comment: What does `System.out.println("Position:"+position+"NewVal:"+newVal);` output

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove quantityList=null; in MainActivity.java

2) Remove TextView tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText); in MultiSelectionAdapter.java. Duplicate code. You have initialized to tv1.

3) Implement callback in adapter

```
 private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;

 public static interface AdapterCallback {
    void onCallback(int position, int value);
 }

 public MultiSelectionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mList = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.mList = list;

        try {
            this.mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }

 }

 public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

    if (newVal > 0) {

        mAdapterCallback.onCallback(position, newVal);
        tv1.setText(Integer.toString(newVal));

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCallback(int position, int value) {
            quantityList.put(position, value);

}
```